# Flash builder newbie- when i run a flex project the browser displays a blank screen

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.5, flash-builder4.5

I am learning Flex v4.6-> Flash Builder.

Now, I created a simple flex project that has one single label in its UI. I saved the project and tried to run it-- a new page opens in browser, however this page is displayed as blank-- the label is not shown.

My OS is Windows 8 Pro and browser= Google Chrome.

Why is a blank screen being displayed in Chrome? How do I resolve this problem? I am simply following instructions from a book on Flex, and have added the single label as per instructions. Book name is Adobe Flex 4.5 Fundamentals: Training from the Source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known, intermittent issue with Flash Debug in Chrome, unfortunately. The generated HTML page tends to not work properly. For most debugging purposes, I would either try a different browser (I believe IE9, and presumably 10, and Firefox have worked in the past for me) or debug with the actual debug player rather than the browser.

To switch the Debug Player, do this in FlashBuilder

1. Run > Debug Configurations...
2. That should default to the current project. If not, go to that project using the sidebar
3. In the settings area, you should see a section titled "URL or Path to Launch." Uncheck "Use Default"
4. Browse to and select your SWF, rather than your HTML page

That will open it in the Flash Player and eliminate Chrome from the equation

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I've noticed is it's blank if their are other tabs open. Close a tab and the Flash magically appears.